# Validate only the signature of JWT token generated from Azure B2C AD

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

I want to validate only the signature of the token which I recieve after logging with `Azure B2C AD`.

Examples showed in the web, use a secret or key parameter, which I'm not sure from where I can get them if `Azure B2C AD` generates the token.

If it's possbile, how can I achieve only that signature validation without more validations for `Audience` etc ?

**EDIT** it uses `"alg": "RS256"`

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840170/validating-the-token-recieved-from-azure-ad-b2c-using-the-values-from-jwks-uri
The best one I found

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has [an example application](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet) which uses `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` from AAD IdentityModel Extensions for .Net to validate JWT tokens, including signatures. [Here is the code that does the actual validation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs), which leverages `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`. I suppose if you wanted to strip out just the signature validation code you could pull that from [the ValidateToken or ValidateSignature methods in the source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs).

Comment: What about the key parameter that these methods expect, what exactly should I provide. I looked upon this endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_sign_in but im still confused.

Comment: This all uses the OpenID Connect protocol. If you're interested in how that works, [you can find a ton of stuff online](https://www.google.com/search?q=introduction+to+openid+connect). [This article](https://www.pingidentity.com/developer/en/resources/openid-connect-developers-guide.html) has a specific section on validating OpenID Connect signatures using keys from the well-known OIDC endpoints

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041219/4990859 and it did the work. It's done.