# ASP NET CORE Identity and Checktoken URL

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Well, I'm trying to use ASP NET CORE 2.1 with OAuth2 to authenticate in a IdP (Identity Provider), so I have the following:

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    // The API resource scope issued in authorization server
                    options.Audience = "resource.server.api";
                    // URL of my authorization server
                    options.Authority = "https://myidp.com.br";
                });

            // Making JWT authentication scheme the default
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
```

When I try to call my API thought POSTMAN, I got following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://myidp.com.br/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

Well, I don't have *well-known* URL in my IdP and I can't add it in this moment of project. Is there other way to configure URLs manually without well-known ?

Another important thing: We have a URL `https://myidp.com.br/oauth/tokeninfo` that check if JWT TOKEN is valid or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the `Asymmetric Keys` . Usually, the public key information is automatically retrieved from the discovery document. If you need to specify it manually, you’ll need to get the key parameters and create a SecurityKey object . You can refer to belwo links for code samples :

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/src/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L148

[Verifying JWT signed with the RS256 algorithm using public key in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403823/verifying-jwt-signed-with-the-rs256-algorithm-using-public-key-in-c-sharp)

You can also write the custom `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` in the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package` , and override the `ValidateToken` event to implement the custom validation logic .

You can also not using the `AddJwtBearer` middleware , the code sample is same as [above](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/src/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L148) , create your keys and apply to the validation .

Normally , the noraml process of validating token is :

- Decode token
- Validate claims(issuer,audience,expire time...)
- Validate signature
- Creating user principal and sign in user

**Updated :**

You can also add your own signature validation to the TokenValidationParameters :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {

        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        SignatureValidator =
        delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
        {

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("xxxxxx"),
            };

            //pass toekn to your endpoint and check result 

            if (false)
            {
                throw new Exception("Token signature validation failed.");
            }

            return jwt;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: But I don't want to validate the token in offline mode. I would like to call my IdP to validate it for me.

Comment: That up to you how to get the keys , you can get keys from idp in above options , they all support customize logic

Comment: In my IdP I have a URL /tokeninfo and I can use it to validate the token (return 200 if ok).

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas Then write your custom to make http client request to get result , for example , in SignatureValidator . See updated reply

Comment: It works, but I think is very strange Net Core 2.1 don't have any easy way (like Spring Security) to insert a URL Tokeninfo in properties without any code.

Comment: The default logic is consume metadata to retire keys for validating . You need to customize the logic .In addition , please mark as answer which may help others who meet same problem