# Cannot decrypt string using PEM files and RSA in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, rsa

I have not been able to decrypt strings in C# using .pem files generated by SSL. I don't think I understand the algorithm enough and looked at several threads and none of them worked for me including this article:

https://gist.github.com/dziwoki/cc41b523c2bd43ee646b957f0aa91943

and this thread:

[Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927791/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-org-bouncycastle-asn1-dersequence-to-type-org-b)

I am encrypting the data using SSL (from the git command line) as below:

```
1. Create a private key:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_pubexp:65537 -out myprivkey.pem

2. Generate a public key from the private key:
openssl pkey -pubout -in myprivkey.pem -out mypubkey.pem

3. Create test string:
echo rsatest > teststring.txt

4. Encrypt the string with the public key:
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey mypubkey.pem -pubin -in teststring.txt -out teststring.out.enc

5. Decrypt the string:
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey myprivkey.pem -in teststring.out.enc -out clear_text.txt
```

What I want to do in C# is basically line 5 of the steps above.  Yet, I cannot get it to work. The code always throws an exception 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair' Here is the sample I am trying:

```
    static string decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        PemReader pr = new PemReader(
            (StreamReader)File.OpenText(@"D:\rsa_decryption\myprivkey.pem")
        );

        // ***HELP*** This object never casts!
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();

        // PKCS1 OAEP paddings
        OaepEncoding eng = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
        eng.Init(false, keys.Private);

        int length = cipherTextBytes.Length;
        int blockSize = eng.GetInputBlockSize();
        List<byte> plainTextBytes = new List<byte>();
        for (int chunkPosition = 0;
            chunkPosition < length;
            chunkPosition += blockSize)
        {
            int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, length - chunkPosition);
            plainTextBytes.AddRange(eng.ProcessBlock(
                cipherTextBytes, chunkPosition, chunkSize
            ));
        }

        String result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes.ToArray());
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know these classes but from the docs RsaKeyParameters is an AsymmetricKeyParameter not an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair. You can pass an RsaKeyParameters to the AsymmetricCipherKeyPair constructor though - it wants two, so I'd guess you can use the same value for both for RSA.

Comment: thanks man! that was it :)

Comment: This is the full answer for my original question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036132/cannot-decrypt-in-c-sharp-an-encrypted-string-done-by-openssl-always-get-org-bo